# npm install is not installing dependencies of dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

When I `npm install` my node application, my the packages list in the `dependencies` property of my `package.json` are installed. But, for some reason some of those dependencies are not installing their sub-dependencies. In other words, there is no node_modules folder with the dependencies of my dependencies.

```
myproject
- node_modules
  - my-package
    - node_modules (would expect this to be here, but it's not)
```

The strange thing is that is another project, the sub-dependencies are being installed for the same packages.

Even when I try to manually install a single package via `npm install my-package`, that packages node_modules are not installed.

Is there a reason why this might be the case? Or a way I can debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Newer versions of NPM flatten the `node_modules` hierarchy to avoid extremely long file paths. Check the upper most `node_modules` level for the sub-depenencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NPM tries to flatten your dependencies at the root level. If is a version that satisfies all of your dependencies(Either only one package the dependency, or the version satisfies all package requirements as defined in package.json) it will roll it up to the root of your node_modules. This is done intentionally, so that you do not installed the same dependency multiple times.

The exception to this rule occurs if there are conflicting versions of a module e.g. package1 has dependency a version 1.0.1 and package2 has dependency a version 2.

Comment: Thanks Mike. The thing is, for my particular use-case I wish it didn't do this, because I need to be sure of the filepath because I need to insert a license into one of the sub-dependencies. The fact that it may have rolled up the sub-dependency in one project and not another is a bit concerning.

Comment: Did you write the sub-dependency?

Comment: In the end I found that there was an unused, unwanted version hanging around in the package-lock.json. Once I got rid of that, then just a single version of the sub-dependency was installed (up at the top-level of node_modules).

Answer (score 2):

I opened a similar question and was brought back to this one where I see a lack of an actual solution.
I've currently managed to find it and the correct one to get your package to install its own `node_modules` is to add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"bundledDependencies": [
    "npm-package"
]
```

To that array, add the packages you want to be installed in the `node_modules` folder `of my-package`:

```
myproject
- node_modules
  - my-package
    - node_modules <-- This folder will contain the packages of the array
```

So, an example of package json could be:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "yargs": "13.2"
  },
  "bundledDependencies": [
    "yargs",
    "jsdom"
  ]
}
```

When you will install `my-package` inside one other project it will have it's own `node_modules` with the packages specified in `bundledDependencies`.